# Django: Generic detail view must be called with either an object pk or a slug

Tags: python, django

Getting this error when submitting the form associated with this view. Not sure what exactly is the problem, considering I have a form with a very similar structure and it works fine.

```
#views.py
class Facture_Creer(SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView):
    model = Facture
    template_name = "facturation/nouvelle_facture.html"
    form_class= FormulaireFacture

    # permet de retourner a l'URL pointant vers le membre modifie
    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('facture_consulter',kwargs={'pk': self.get_object().id})

class Facture_Update(SuccessMessageMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Facture
    template_name = "facturation/nouvelle_facture.html"
    form_class= FormulaireFacture
    success_message = "Facture mise à jour avec succes"

    # permet de retourner a l'URL pointant vers le membre modifie
    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('facture_consulter',kwargs={'pk': self.get_object().id})

#urls.py
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="facturation/index.html")),
    url(r'^facture/$', FactureView.as_view()),
    url(r'^facture/(?P<id>\d+)', FactureView.as_view(), name='facture_consulter'),
    url(r'^facture/ajouter/$', Facture_Creer.as_view(), name='facture_creer'),
    url(r'^facture/modifier/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', Facture_Update.as_view(), name='facture_update'),
    url(r'^membre/ajouter/$', Membre_Creer.as_view(), name='membre_creer'),
    url(r'^membre/modifier/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', Membre_Update.as_view(), name='membre_update'),
    #url(r'membre/(?P<pk>\d+)/supprimer/$', Membre_Supp.as_view(), name='membre_delete')
)

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

Comment: Just a side note: never _ever, ever, ever_, use non-English words for views as done in this example. (`Member`, `Facture`, `Creer` etc.) This makes your code base much, much harder to work with for people speaking other languages (than French in this case), and it looks rather ugly.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You need to pass an object identifier (pk or slug) so your views know which object they're operating on.

Just to take an example from your `urls.py`:

```
url(r'^facture/ajouter/$', Facture_Creer.as_view(), name='facture_creer'),
url(r'^facture/modifier/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', Facture_Update.as_view(), name='facture_update'),
```

See how the second one has `(?P<pk>\d+)/`? That is passing a pk to the UpdateView so it knows which object to use. Thus if you go to `facture/modifier/5/`, then the UpdateView will modify object with pk of 5.

If you don't want to pass a pk or slug in your url, you'll need to override the [get_object()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_object) method and get your object another way. Url [here](http://chriskief.com/2012/12/29/django-generic-detailview-without-a-pk-or-slug/).

Comment: Makes sense. The problem seems to be located on the 
    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('facture_consulter',kwargs={'pk': self.get_object().id}) 

part. Do you know of a way to get the saved object out of a CreateView ?

Comment: Nevermind, found it out. Thanks for the quick answer to my question !

Comment: Does it have to be 'pk' always or can it be a different name too?

Comment: @user763410 You can, but you'll need to overwrite the `get_object()` method on the view you're using. Documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_object)

Comment: Note that I had to restart Django's dev webserver in order for this to work

Comment: How about Django 3?

Answer (score 17):

As Alex suggests: for default Django behaviour you have to use "pk" in your url pattern.

If you wish to change the object identifier for the primary key "pk" to a different name, you can define [pk_url_kwarg](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.pk_url_kwarg). This is available since Django 1.4.

Answer (score 8):

Hey all I used the new `path()` function and here is my working example that I'm sure will help:

views.py:

```
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView

class ContentAmpView(DetailView):

    model = Content
    template_name = 'content_amp.html'  # Defaults to content_detail.html
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path

from .views import ContentAmpView

# My pk is a string so using a slug converter here intead of int
urlpatterns = [
    path('<slug:pk>/amp', ContentAmpView.as_view(), name='content-amp'),
]
```

templates/content_amp.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html amp lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
    <title>Hello, AMPs</title>
    <link rel="canonical" href="http://example.ampproject.org/article-metadata.html">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1">
    <script type="application/ld+json">
      {
        "@context": "http://schema.org",
        "@type": "NewsArticle",
        "headline": "Open-source framework for publishing content",
        "datePublished": "2015-10-07T12:02:41Z",
        "image": [
          "logo.jpg"
        ]
      }

    </script>
    <style amp-boilerplate>
        body{-webkit-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-moz-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-ms-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both}@-webkit-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-moz-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-ms-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-o-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}
    </style>
    <noscript>
        <style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:none;-moz-animation:none;-ms-animation:none;animation:none}
        </style>
    </noscript>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to AMP - {{ object.pk }}</h1>
<p>{{ object.titles.main }}</p>
<p>Reporter: {{ object.reporter }}</p>
<p>Date: {{ object.created_at|date }}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Also note that in my `settings.py`, under `TEMPLATES`, I have `'APP_DIRS': True`. More on path [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/urls/#django.urls.path).

Comment: thanks, this helped. I was missing a `:pk` part in the `path`

Comment: Thanks as well. I had :id instead of :pk in my path. Live and learn

Answer (score 6):

Like Robin said, you can use `pk_url_kwarg` if you want custom pk name.

But as addition, issue *Generic detail view must be called with either an object pk or a slug* raises also in slug.

So if you want to create **custom slug field** (no need to use *pk* or *slug* name). You can override `slug_field` and `slug_url_kwarg` in your DetailView class.

Here is just another example if you want url as Slug Field.

**models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    url = models.SlugField()
    body = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='blog/', blank=True, null=True)
```

**views.py**

```
class ListPost(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/list.html'
    paginate_by = 2
    context_object_name = 'posts'

class DetailPost(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/detail.html'
    slug_field = 'url'
    slug_url_kwarg = 'url'
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', ListPost.as_view()),
    path('<slug:url>/', DetailPost.as_view()),
]
```

Answer (score 2):

I am using Django version 2.2.12,

Here is just another example this works fine for me :

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    pages = models.IntegerField()
    price = models.FloatField()
```

**views.py**

```
from django.views.generic import ListView,DetailView
from testapp.models import Book

class BookListView(ListView):
    model=Book

class BookDetailView(DetailView):
    model=Book
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from testapp import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.BookListView.as_view()),
    path('<slug:pk>/', views.BookDetailView.as_view()),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use a CreateView, the error also, raised.
The solution is:

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
  self.object = None
```

Answer (score -3):

Update: In django 2.0.2, change this to:

```
url(r'^facture/modifier/<int:pk>/$', Facture_Update.as_view(), name='facture_update'),
```

Comment: This won't work. The behaviour of the `url()` function is not changed in Django 2.x and still works as  before. You are probably thinking of the new [`path()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urls/#path) function.