# The view ... didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: django, httpresponse

I have a view that is throwing me the following error "The view Apps.General.localidades_vistas.Localidad_Crear did not return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead." when I try to save a new "localidad"... I pass the code to see if you can help me.

views.py

```py
class Localidad_List(ListView):
    model = localidades
    template_name = 'general/localidad_list.html'
    def get_queryset(self):
        buscar = self.request.GET.get('buscalo')
        if buscar:
            object_list = localidades.objects.filter(localidad__contains = buscar)
        else:
            object_list = localidades.objects.all()
        return object_list

class Localidad_Crear(CreateView):
    model = localidades
    form_class = LocalidadForm
    template_name = 'general/localidad_form.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('general:localidad_listar')

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            modelo = form.save(commit=False)
            modelo.clocalidad = localidad_max() #'99'
            #print(localidad_max())
            usuario = self.request.user
            modelo.usumodi = str(usuario)
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('general:localidad_listar')

class Localidad_Edit(UpdateView):
    model = localidades
    form_class = LocalidadForm
    template_name = 'general/localidad_form.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('general:localidad_listar')

class Localidad_Delete(DeleteView):
    model = localidades
    template_name = 'general/localidad_delete.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('general:localidad_listar')      

def localidad_max():
    try:
        cvalor = localidades.objects.latest('clocalidad').clocalidad
    except:
        cvalor = '0'
    cvalor = str(int(cvalor) + 1)
    return cvalor.zfill(5)

def provincia_load(request):
    cpais = request.GET.get('cpais')
    xprovincias = provincias.objects.filter(cpais = cpais).order_by('provincia')
    return render(request,'general/combo_provincia.html', {'provincias':xprovincias})
```

urls.py

```py
from .views import from .localidades_vistas import Localidad_List, Localidad_Edit, Localidad_Delete, Localidad_Crear, provincia_load
#, Provincia_Crear, Provincia_Edit, Provincia_Delete

app_name = 'general'

urlpatterns = [
    path('',index, name = 'index'),
    #--------------------- Localidades ---------------------------    
    path('localidades',Localidad_List.as_view(), name = 'localidad_listar'),
    path('localidad_nuevo',Localidad_Crear.as_view(), name = 'localidad_crear'),
    path('localidad_editar/<pk>/',Localidad_Edit.as_view(), name = 'localidad_editar'),
    path('localidad_eliminar/<pk>/',Localidad_Delete.as_view(), name = 'localidad_eliminar'),    
    path('ajax/provincias/', provincia_load, name = 'ajax_provincias'),    
]
```

forms.py

```py
from django import forms
from .models import paises, provincias, localidades

class LocalidadForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = localidades
        # con esto añades un campo de texto que te permite realizar la busqueda, puedes añadir mas de un atributo por el cual se filtrará
        search_fields = ['localidad']

        fields = [
            'localidad',
            'cp',
            'cpais',
            'cprovincia',
            'vigente',
        ]

        labels = {
            'localidad' : 'Localidad',
            'cp' : 'Cod. Postal',
            'cpais' : 'País',
            'cprovincia' : 'Provincia',
            'vigente' : 'Vigente',
        }
        widget= {
            'localidad' :forms.TextInput(attrs = {'class':'form-control'}),
            'cp' :forms.TextInput(attrs = {'class':'form-control'}),
            'cpais' :forms.Select(attrs = {'class':'form-control'}),
    }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['cprovincia'].queryset = provincias.objects.none()
        if 'cpais' in self.data:
            try:
                cpais = int(self.data.get('cpais'))
                self.fields['cprovincia'].queryset = provincias.objects.filter(cpais = cpais).order_by('provincia')
            except (ValueError, TypeError):
                pass
        elif self.instance.pk:
            self.fields['cprovincia'].queryset = self.instance.cpais.provincias_set.order_by('provincia')
```

localidad_form.html

```
{% extends 'base/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    <form method="post" id="Localidad_Form" data-provincias-url="{% url 'general:ajax_provincias' %}" novalidate >
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p}}
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type= "submit">Guardar</button>
    </form>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#id_cpais").change(function () {
            var url = $("#Localidad_Form").attr("data-provincias-url");  
            var paisId = $(this).val();  
            $.ajax({                       
            data: {
                'cpais': paisId      
                },
            success: function (data) {  
                $("#id_cprovincia").html(data);  
            }
            }); 
        });
    });
    </script>
</div>
{% endblock %}
{% block filtros %}
    <td>
        <a class="btn btn-success btn-sm" href="{% url 'general:provincia_crear' %}">Agregar Provincia</a>
        <a class="btn btn-success btn-sm" href="{% url 'general:pais_crear' %}">Agregar País</a>
    </td>
{% endblock %}
```

combo_provincia.html

```
<option value="">---------</option>
{% for provincia in provincias %}
<option value="{{ provincia.cprovincia }}">{{ provincia.provincia }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

Thanks in advance.

PD: I have a couple dropdown chained that work well and that was the subject of another query. :-)

Comment: You shouldn't be overriding the `post` (or `get`) method at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your post function is missing a return if `form.is_valid` is false. You need to add the `else` part.

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            modelo = form.save(commit=False)
            modelo.clocalidad = localidad_max() #'99'
            #print(localidad_max())
            usuario = self.request.user
            modelo.usumodi = str(usuario)
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)
```

You could move the logic in the `is_valid` block to the `form_valid` method and don't override `post`. You can easily check [here](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.1/django.views.generic.edit/CreateView/) the default code of the methods.

Comment: gdef_... I tried your code and he shoots me 'Localidad_Crear' object has no attribute 'object'

Comment: Check the updated answer. Add the `self.object = self.get_object()` line

Comment: now generates the error "Generic detail view Locality_Create must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf."

Comment: That is another different error in another part of the code, the original asked question was resolved. For the new error make another question or check for an existing one. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23154525/django-generic-detail-view-must-be-called-with-either-an-object-pk-or-a-slug) for example.

Comment: I just added the html codes that complete the coding. The rest of the project code has already been tested by me satisfactorily. Thanks for your time.

Comment: When I pull out the javascript (and the ajax request) from locality_form.html, it works !! ... Something is missing me

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this problem because you havn't written a HttpResponse object if request type is not POST

To overcome this in your view write somthing which will process if request type is not post

```py
    form = SearchForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        f = SearchForm(request.POST)
        if f.is_valid():
            Pets = Pet.objects.filter(animal = f.cleaned_data["text"])
            return HttpResponseRedirect("search.html",{"Pets":Pets},{"form":form})
```