# Attribute Error: Generic Detail View must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf in tests

Tags: python, django, pytest

I've spent a lot of time today reviewing other posts that reference this issue both here and throughout Google. I cannot, however, find a solution when this occurs in a test. I am using pytest in my project and get this error on one of my detail views only when testing the view. The view itself works on my actual site. Here's my code:

views.py

```
class CarrierDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = Carrier
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        quotes = self.object.quotes.all()
        context['quotes'] = quotes
        return context
```

models.py

```
class Carrier(models.Model):
    TYPE_CHOICES = [
        ('WYO', 'WYO'),
        ('PRIVATE', 'Private')
    ]
    carrier_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    carrier_type = models.CharField(max_length=7, choices=TYPE_CHOICES)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.carrier_name
```

urls.py

```
    path('carrier/<int:pk>/', views.CarrierDetailView.as_view(), name='carrier-detail'),
```

and test_views.py

```
class CarrierDetailViewTest(TestCase):
    def test_carrier_detail_view(self):
        self.factory = RequestFactory()
        self.carrier = models.Carrier.objects.create(carrier_name='NatGen', carrier_type='WYO', id=2)
        path = reverse('quote-checklist:carrier-detail', kwargs={'pk':2})
        request = RequestFactory().get(path)
        request.user = User.objects.create_user(username='ryan', email='ryan@email.com', password='password')
        response = views.CarrierDetailView.as_view()(request, kwargs={'pk':2})
        assert response.status_code == 200

    def test_carrier_detail_template(self):
        assert('carrier_detail.html')
```

Please note in the tests I've received this error both with the kwargs in the response/path and without. I've also successfully tested the url for this view using the following test code:

```
    def test_carrier_detail_view_url(self):
        path = reverse('quote-checklist:carrier-detail', kwargs={'pk':1})
        assert resolve(path).view_name == 'quote-checklist:carrier-detail'
```

I appreciate in advance any insight others may have to offer.

Comment: I've got issues in unit tests as well, so I'm very interested with you issue and finding a solution. In your case, I would try to change `path = reverse('quote-checklist:carrier-detail', kwargs={'pk':2})` with `path = reverse('quote-checklist:carrier-detail', args=[self.carrier.id])` (if I understood that the pk in your url is this one - I personally would have write 'carrier_id' in urls.py to remind me which id is required - anyway the main point is in the syntax). No guaranty it'll work...

Comment: Thank you for the input on this. I gave this a try but unfortunately get the same error.

Comment: Thanks for the try and sorry it didn't work... I'll follow your subject

Comment: Did you notice this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23154525/django-generic-detail-view-must-be-called-with-either-an-object-pk-or-a-slug?rq=1?

Comment: Try to use `response = views.CarrierDetailView.as_view()(request, **{'pk':2})`

Comment: This was the answer! Thank you bdbd!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer turned out to be bdbd's suggestion. I changed my response to

```
response = views.CarrierDetailView.as_view()(request, **{'pk':2})
```

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `quotes = self.object.quotes.all()` to `quotes = self.get_object().quotes.all()`