# How to display a query on DetailView in Django?

Tags: django, detailview

I want my "CustomDetailView" to display a query(a single "flashcard"). I was able to it by using ListView

```
CustomListView(ListView):
    model = Flashcard
    template_name = 'flashcards.html
    queryset = Flashcard.objects.all()[:1]
```

But for DetaiView I'm getting this error
**Generic detail view CustomDetailView must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf.**

```
class CustomDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Flashcard 
    template_name = "flashcards.html"
    queryset = Flashcard.objects.all().first()
```

urls.py

`path('', CustomDetailView.as_view(), name='flashcards'),`

How to fix this?

Comment: What does your url config look like? It seems to be missing a pk or slug.

Comment: Note you shouldn't use `.first()` in a detail view, it will search for a pk based on the url

Comment: You need to pass an object identifier (pk or slug) in urls.py file.
Please refer this link.
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23154525/django-generic-detail-view-must-be-called-with-either-an-object-pk-or-a-slug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23154525/django-generic-detail-view-must-be-called-with-either-an-object-pk-or-a-slug)

Comment: @mousetail path('', CustomDetailView.as_view(), name='flashcards'),       Why do I need pk when it worked for listview?

Comment: Why would a list view need a pk? A list view shows multiple items so has no need for a specific pk. A detail view shows a single item thus needs the pk of a specific item.

Comment: @mousetail Just wanted to pick a random or first query when I click a link and show it on detailView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe should have better communicated. Sorry for my English.
I wanted to return a random query when I clicked on a link a show it on detailView. I was able to it by this. Don't think it's efficient. If anyone has any idea share it.

```
def get_object(self):
    queryset = Flashcard.objects.order_by('?').first()
    return queryset
```

Answer (score 3):

remove **first** from queryset:

```
class CustomDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Flashcard 
    template_name = "flashcards.html"
    queryset = Flashcard.objects.all()
    lookup_field = 'pk'
    lookup_url_kwarg = 'pk'
    enter code here
```

and add **id** to url:

```
path('/<int:pk>/', CustomDetailView.as_view(), name='flashcards'),
```

Comment: Thanks. I think I have to ask another question. How to generate a random int so I when I click on the link I go to the desired page. خیلی ممنون

Answer (score 0):

You need your `pk` or `slug` in

```
path('', CustomDetailView.as_view(), name='flashcards'),
```

See an example from the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview):

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('<slug:slug>/', ArticleDetailView.as_view(), name='article-detail'),
]
```

This is because [DetailView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview) is inheriting from [SingleObjectMixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#singleobjectmixin), and it fetches objects that way. If you want, jump to definition of this class in your IDE to see its implementation of `get_queryset` and `get_object`.

How you call your `pk` or `slug` really depends on your model, the `Flashcard`. If your `primary_key` field is an `Integer`, I think you'll be fine writing

```
path('<int:pk>', CustomDetailView.as_view(), name='flashcards'),
```

**edit**: as [Pourya Mansouri wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75408100/3694363), you do need to remove queryset attribute in your case too

The `slug` you can customize with [slug_field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.slug_field) and similar attributes.

You can define a completely custom object fetching behavior by overriding [get_object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_object) or [get_queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_queryset). Here's a random examples of doing that I found on the internet:

- Overriding `get_object`: https://www.valentinog.com/blog/detail/
- Overriding `get_queryset`: https://www.agiliq.com/blog/2019/01/django-when-and-how-use-detailview/